# What controls the placement of links relative to the body?

Tags: 8

I am struggling with getting the "Read more" and "Add new comment" links placed *below* the body on a custom node content type called "Wikitext" that has been created using the GUI on a Drupal 8.9.17 website.

The site is running the default theme (Bartik) and I have not edited any templates. The built-in content type "Article" shows these links below the body.  "Wikitext" is supposed to be identical to "Article", but displays them *above* the body.

I've unticked "Show reply form on the same page as comments" on the comment settings form for both content types.

Below the acreenshot is a copy of the "Manage display" form. It is identical for both content types, and has "Links" and "Comments" as the last two fields to display.

I have looked very carefully, but cannot locate anywhere in the GUI where I can control the placements of these links.  Does anybody know where to look?

[image: Screenshot showing link placement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *Links* field that appears also the question's screenshot, but for the *Teaser* view mode, whose settings are on /admin/structure/types/manage/wikitext/display/teaser, for the *Wikitext* content type. (I assume *wikitext* is the machine name for that content type.)

I changed the *Teaser* view mode for the *Article* content type and re-ordered the fields as follows.

> [image: screenshot]

This is how an article appears now in the front page, once it's promoted on front page.

> [image: screenshot]